# Cannot set up remote access to a MySQL server on Linux

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I'm trying to set up my MySQL server on my Debian Linux system for remote access. However, I'm encountering an issue where I can't set the "bind-address" variable. I have attempted to set it using the command `mysqladmin --bind-address=0.0.0.0` and it returns `mysqladmin: unknown variable 'bind-address=0.0.0.0'`.

I have also tried inserting this:

`[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

into both `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as well as `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` and restarting the server by running `service mysql restart`

I would run `lsof -Pni :3306` to see if it took the bind-address from the config file and was listening outside of its local IP and it would return

`COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  28978 mysql   20u  IPv4 148539      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)`

Which indicated to me that it was still only listening locally.
I have checked the `/etc/default/mysql` file to make sure that there weren't any startup options set that were stopping me from being able to access it remotely.

I have tried with the protocol option set to both "TCP" and "SOCKET" but neither work.

How can I get MySQL to listen outside of its local network?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. check mysql version

   `mysql --version`

Default value of bind-address shows below:

- Default Value (>= 5.6.6)  *
- Default Value (<= 5.6.5)  0.0.0.0

So actually don't need set bind-address for above mysql version.

2. check mysql config file location

   `$ which mysqld
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
    $ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
    Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

check is there any bind-address config in above config files.

3. restart mysqld service

   `service mysqld restart`
4. confirm mysql user created with `user@'%'` to allow user connect mysql outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.1

sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add the following to the file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Save the file and exit.

```
mysql -u admin -p -P3307 -h 192.168.2.110
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. It might be worth using the formatting available here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make the answer easier to read.